# Jquery convert dynamic form data to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am working with my project that will create quizzes that form. I want it to be submitted into json format, which will be look like this:

```
[
    {
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Who is Mark Zuckerberg?",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "answer": "Facebook CEO",
                        "correct": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "answer": "Google Programmer",
                        "correct": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "question": "Who is the founder of Apple?",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "answer": "Mark Zuckerberg",
                        "correct": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answer": "Bill Gates",
                        "correct": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answer": "Steve Jobs",
                        "correct": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have my form that allows the user to add & delete questions and options. User can also select the correct answer in the list of options.

Here is the [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uoaee1tc/).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <button id="btn-add-tab" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Question</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <form id="form">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" tab="1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Question 1</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
                        <br>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" placeholder="Your question" required>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="add-option" type="button">Add Option</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div id="options">
                                <!--- OPTIONS -->
                                <div class="well">
                                    <textarea id="answer" class="form-control" placeholder="Your answer" required></textarea>
                                    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" id="correct-answer" name="correct-ans-1" required>Correct Answer</label></div>
                                </div>
                                <!--- END OPTIONS -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button id="btn-get-json" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-block">Get JSON</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With myjavascript code, I am experiencing an error which only shows json from the first question. Also, it doesn't display the list of options. In my code I used `each` to get all input fields in the form. Then I used `JSON.stringify();` to convert array to JSON.

```
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        var jsonArr = [];
        var obj = {};

        var questionsArr = [];
        var questionsCont = {};
        var tabs = $("#form :input:not(input[type='submit'],button[type='button'])");
        $(tabs).each(function(k,v){
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var value = $(this).val();
            questionsCont[id] = value;
        });
        questionsArr.push(questionsCont);
        obj["questions"] = questionsArr;

        jsonArr.push(obj);
        var json = JSON.stringify(jsonArr, null, "\t");
        alert(json);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I would like to have a json result that will looked-like from the post above. For testing my code, please see this [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uoaee1tc/).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, IDs are meant to be unique -- so you cannot have two or more elements with the same ID. When you open a new tab or create a new option, you violate that rule.

Therefore, you should change your IDs to classes and/or names (using []). So, what I did is change input elements to use names and other problem elements to use classes.

How I see of going about is to start by looping through each tab pane. On each pane, find the question and its options, and add them to a data structure that will hold all your data. I am using the [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to translate each tab into a question.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var json = {};
    // loop through each tab pane
    json.questions = $('.tab-pane').map(function() {
        return {
            question: $('[name^=question]', this).val(),
            // loop through each answer
            options: $('[name^=answer]', this).map(function() {
                return {
                    answer: $(this).val(),
                    correct: $(this).siblings('.radio').find('[name^=correct-ans]').prop('checked')
                };
            }).get()
        };
    }).get();

    alert(JSON.stringify(json, null, "\t"));
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRRXjw?editors=0010)

Comment: It works! Thanks! But how to avoid selecting two or more correct answer (radio button) in each questions?

Comment: In order to have only one radio button be selected within a group of radio buttons, they need to have the same `name` attribute. However, in your case, there are also multiple groups -- therefore the names of each group need to be different. Seeing that you have a unique number for each tab, we will use it in naming our groups. First tab will consist of input elements ending with `[1]`, such as `correct-ans[1]`. Second tab will consist of elements ending with `[2]` and so forth. Here's the [fix](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mErbzq?editors=0010).